# Laravel не работает сессия и валидация

Tags: laravel, blade

Есть в контроллере `return redirect('/profile')->with('status', 'Profile updated!');`
В отображении

```
@if (session('status'))
        <div class="alert alert-success">
            {{ session('status') }}
        </div>
@endif
```

Но ни чего не показывает
Контроллер с редиректом находится в пакете, если это как то может влиять. В других случаях сессия работает

в шаблоне подключается форма с другой директории

```
@include('forms.form')
```

после нажатия submit, если все ок отрабатывает редирект на ту же страницу,но сессия не записывается.

пробовал и так

```
@if(Session::has('status'))
<div class="alert alert-success">
    {{ Session::get('status') }} 
</div>
@endif
```

проблема также с валидацией, условие отрабатывает, а отображения нет, в исходном коде тоже нет

Comment: Версия laravel?

Comment: версия laravel 6.3

Answer (score 0):

```
return redirect('/profile')->with(['status' => 'Profile updated!']);
```

Или, можно вынести сессию перед редиректом.

```
 session(['status' => 'Profile updated!']);
 return redirect('/profile');
```

***P.S.*** *может не работать по причине того, что вы на роут несколько web-middleware повесили*

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: не работает
только middleware('auth') повешен

Answer (score 0):

```
Session::flash('status', 'Profile updated!');
return redirect('/profile');
```

нужно импортовать класс сессион вверху класа нужно написат

```
use Session;
```

Comment: не работает тоже